# AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'binary_location'

Tags: python

Помогите новичку .
Решил сделать бота по видео , но выбивало ошибки.
Решил порыться на сайтах и решить их , но все же выдает одну ошибку[![на фото код][1]][1]

```
from instapy import InstaPy
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options as 
FirefoxOptions
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options as 
ChromeOptionsdefineOptions
options = {};

options.binary_location = r"C:/Program Files (x86)/Mozilla 
Firefox/firefox.exe"
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options, 
log_path="C:/Users/Oleg/Desktop/geckodriver.exe")
driver.get('http://google.com/')
driver.get('http://inventwithpython.com')
session = InstaPy(username= ".....@gmail.com", password="......")
session.login()

session.like_by_tags(["bmw", "mercedes"], amount=5)

session.set_dont_like(["naked", "nsfw"])

session.set_do_follow(True, percentage=50)

session.set_do_comment(True, percentage=50)

session.set_comments(["Nice!", "Sweet!", "Beautiful :heart_eyes:"])

session.end()
```

Comment: добро пожаловать! Помещайте свой код в вопрос в текстовом формате, чтобы можно было прочитать, копировать и работать с ним, используя блок кода. [Править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1297016/edit)

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего создавать переменную с опциями вам нужно так:

```
options = FirefoxOptions()
```

А вы создаёте просто пустой словарь, у него, конечно, нет такого поля, которому вы что-то пытаетесь присвоить.